how to set up lldb environment in vscode?
all. I am trying to set an environment for lldb in vscode. For example, on the terminal if I run my executable in lldb, I get the following:
(base) cdwalke8@MSLAL0422100041 examples % lldb ./ExampleRunner
(lldb) target create "./ExampleRunner"
Current executable set to '/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/examples/ExampleRunner' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 65031 launched: '/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/examples/ExampleRunner' (x86_64)
dyld[65031]: Library not loaded: ../lib/libex.so
  Referenced from: <953E1B45-2D99-3202-A89D-EEC0565FBD7C> /Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/examples/ExampleRunner
  Reason: tried: '../lib/libex.so' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS../libex.so' (no such file), '../lib/libex.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libex.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libex.so' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
Process 65031 stopped
* thread #1, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007ff813265c66 dyld`__abort_with_payload + 10
dyld`:
->  0x7ff813265c66 <+10>: jae    0x7ff813265c70            ; <+20>
    0x7ff813265c68 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7ff813265c6b <+15>: jmp    0x7ff8131fd170            ; cerror_nocancel
    0x7ff813265c70 <+20>: retq   
Target 0: (ExampleRunner) stopped.

However, if I start lldb and set the environment like this:
(base) cdwalke8@MSLAL0422100041 examples % lldb ./ExampleRunner
(lldb) target create "./ExampleRunner"
Current executable set to '/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/examples/ExampleRunner' (x86_64).
(lldb) env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/Build/lib
(lldb) r
Process 65174 launched: '/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/examples/ExampleRunner' (x86_64)

# This is not really what the program does, I am just replacing with Hello World for simplicity

====================
Hello World!  
====================

Now, when I set this in my launch.json, the debug terminal shows a similar issue as the first example I showed, but I have the enviornment set:
{
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/examples/ExampleRunner",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "environment": [{
                "name":"DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH", 
                "value": "/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/Build/lib",
            }],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}

Why does this not work? Or, rather what should I change to get lldb to set the environment path correctly before it launches the debugger?
Thanks!

I found an answer to pass export variables to lldb. Simply create a file called project.env in your .vscode dir.
Add this to it:
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/Build/lib

Then, change your launch.json to include an envFile setting:
{
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "C/C++: clang build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/examples/ExampleRunner",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file", 
            "envFile": "/Users/cdwalke8/Desktop/Dev/examples/.vscode/project.env"

        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}



Also this works:
not, environment:, and not an array but an object.
      "env": {
        "PORT": "8080",
        "RUST_BACKTRACE": "1"
      },


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
